# Split file using reference in column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

The purpose on this is to split the following file using as reference the column 5

```
336843.75 2395106.25 36289 38580 660                          
336843.75 2395118.75 36290 38580 660                          
336843.75 2395131.25 36291 38580 661                          
336843.75 2395143.75 36292 38580 662                          
336843.75 2395156.25 36293 38580 662                          
336843.75 2395168.75 36294 38580 663                          
336843.75 2495381.25 44311 38580 665                          
336843.75 2495393.75 44312 38580 760                          
336843.75 2495406.25 44313 38580 761                          
336843.75 2495418.75 44314 38580 762                          
336843.75 2495431.25 44315 38580 764                          
336843.75 2495443.75 44316 38580 765                          
336993.75 2394956.25 36277 38592 765                          
336993.75 2394968.75 36278 38592 766                          
336993.75 2394981.25 36279 38592 770
```

With this code i have subtracted the rows in column 5 to identify when there is a gap > of 50. results in column 6

```
awk '{$6=$5-prev5} {prev5=$5; print}' file    

336843.75 2395106.25 36289 38580 660 660                      
336843.75 2395118.75 36290 38580 660 0                        
336843.75 2395131.25 36291 38580 661 1                        
336843.75 2395143.75 36292 38580 662 1                        
336843.75 2395156.25 36293 38580 662 0                        
336843.75 2395168.75 36294 38580 663 1                        
336843.75 2495381.25 44311 38580 665 2                        
336843.75 2495393.75 44312 38580 760 95                       
336843.75 2495406.25 44313 38580 761 1                        
336843.75 2495418.75 44314 38580 762 1                        
336843.75 2495431.25 44315 38580 764 2                        
336843.75 2495443.75 44316 38580 765 1                        
336993.75 2394956.25 36277 38592 765 0                        
336993.75 2394968.75 36278 38592 766 1                        
336993.75 2394981.25 36279 38592 770 4
```

with the result above i will like to split the file in 2 parts, I have mentioned previously should take in consideration the gap > 50 in column 6 to split the files.

I can use the option

```
awk '{print> substr($5,1,1)}' file
```

but it does not work always.

Output desired 2 files

*file1:*

```
336843.75 2395106.25 36289 38580 660 660                      
336843.75 2395118.75 36290 38580 660 0                        
336843.75 2395131.25 36291 38580 661 1                        
336843.75 2395143.75 36292 38580 662 1                        
336843.75 2395156.25 36293 38580 662 0                        
336843.75 2395168.75 36294 38580 663 1                        
336843.75 2495381.25 44311 38580 665 2
```

*file2:*

```
336843.75 2495393.75 44312 38580 760 95
336843.75 2495406.25 44313 38580 761 1
336843.75 2495418.75 44314 38580 762 1
336843.75 2495431.25 44315 38580 764 2
336843.75 2495443.75 44316 38580 765 1                        
336993.75 2394956.25 36277 38592 765 0                        
336993.75 2394968.75 36278 38592 766 1                        
336993.75 2394981.25 36279 38592 770 4
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ c=1 }{ $6=$5-prev }{ prev=$5 }{ print > "file"(NR>1 && $6 > 50? ++c:c) }' file
```

Results:

```
$ head file[12]
==> file1 <==
336843.75 2395106.25 36289 38580 660 660
336843.75 2395118.75 36290 38580 660 0
336843.75 2395131.25 36291 38580 661 1
336843.75 2395143.75 36292 38580 662 1
336843.75 2395156.25 36293 38580 662 0
336843.75 2395168.75 36294 38580 663 1
336843.75 2495381.25 44311 38580 665 2

==> file2 <==
336843.75 2495393.75 44312 38580 760 95
336843.75 2495406.25 44313 38580 761 1
336843.75 2495418.75 44314 38580 762 1
336843.75 2495431.25 44315 38580 764 2
336843.75 2495443.75 44316 38580 765 1
336993.75 2394956.25 36277 38592 765 0
336993.75 2394968.75 36278 38592 766 1
336993.75 2394981.25 36279 38592 770 4
```

Comment: it works perfect. kindly can you explain the part of the code ++c:c is this the increment on the file name..

Comment: @user2734334, welcome, `$6 > 50? ++c:c` condition will define a suffix for the filename: it starts from `1` and increments it on encountering each "gap"